# Iterating through the first 30 keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored into a variable called `$data`

```
["data"]=>
  array(413) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#254 (7) {
      ["Energy"]=>
      string(7) "44555"
      ["Closing"]=>
      string(10) "102"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#260 (7) {
      ["Energy"]=>
      string(7) "2522"
      ["Closing"]=>
      string(10) "854"
    }
```

And I obtain an arithmetic mean for all the Closing values like this:

```
// initialize sum and total
$sum = 0;
$total = 0;

foreach ($data->data as $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->Closing)) {   // verify that the current object has a Closing
        $sum += $obj->Closing;    // add it to the sum
        $total++;                  // increment the count
    }
}
echo $sum / $total;                // display the average
```

The problem is that now I will only need the first 30 key from the array, but I don't know how to do that, can anyone help me please? I have tried with a for loop but it doesn't do the trick. Any ideas? Thank you all in advance for your time and help.

Comment: IS that just the first 30 or the first 30 that have a value in `$obj->Closing`

Comment: the first 30 with that value

Comment: Then @Tektiv answer is the one for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your second piece of code :

```
$sum = 0;
$total = 0;

foreach ($data->data as $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->Closing) && $total < 30) {   // Closing? + numOfValues < 30 ?
        $sum += $obj->Closing;
        $total++;
    }
}

// Display the average
echo $sum / $total;
```

Adding **`&& $total < 30`** should do the trick since you count how many items you add.

---

You can break out of the `for` if you don't want to do extra loops with a single extra condition :
(thanks *Adam* for pointing this out)

```
foreach ($data->data as $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->Closing) && $total < 30) {
        // ...
    }
    else if ($total >= 30) break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, this solved my problem! Many of the answers are correct but this one I found to be of better use in my case.

Answer (score 2):

To get first N elements of an array, use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function.

```
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 30);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this neat method wont check that all 30 occurances have a value in `$obj->Closing`

Comment: Indeed that is my problem, but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the current answer is that it won't actually break out of the loop when it reaches 30. Surely, it's just a case of breaking out when $total=30?

```
// initialize sum and total
$sum = 0;
$total = 0;
$max = 30;

foreach ($data->data as $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->Closing)) { 
        $sum += $obj->Closing;
        $total++;
        if($total==$max){
            break;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer is correct and applicable but I found another to be of better use in my case. But this is correct too and thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

So there is this old school way of doing things called a for loop.

```
$dataArray = $data->data;

for($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i++){
    $obj = $dataArray[$i]; //Just like the object you have.
    //Do your thing with $obj.
    //Loop will only run 30 times
}
```

I was not sure the structure of your array but `$data->data` seems to be an array.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me in other cases, but for this specific case another solution was "fitting better". But thank you and this is correct too!

Answer (score 0):

In case you love iterators. You can do it combining CallbackFilterIterator and LimitIterator

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator($data->data);
$filtered = new CallbackFilterIterator($iterator, function ($current, $key, $iterator) {
    return isset($current->Closing);
});
//now $filtered have only objects with Closing property
$limited = new LimitIterator($filtered, 0, 30);
$sum = 0;
foreach ($limited as $obj) {
    $sum += $obj->Closing;
}
echo $sum/iterator_count($limited);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but these methods are a bit too complicated for my problem, but thank you again this method works too :)